# Sorting array with timestamp

Tags: php

Im trying to create sort button for list but ive got this list, and i dont know what to do with this timestamp is it possible to sort with it, here is my array type, i hope you will help me guys here it it:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 17
    [ticket] => 17
    [1] => Name Second Name
    [author] => Name Second Name 
    [2] => modules
    [subject] => modules
    [3] => 1412335833
    [timestamp] => 1412335833
    [4] => 1414048041
    [activity] => 1414048041
    [5] => Closed
    [type] => Closed
    [6] => 3
    [priority] => 3
    [7] => 13
    [assignment] => 13
    [8] => 17
)

Array
(
    [0] => 18
    [ticket] => 18
    [1] => Name Second Name 
    [author] => Name Second Name
    [2] => modules
    [subject] => modules
    [3] => 1412335935
    [timestamp] => 1412335935
    [4] => 1414048095
    [activity] => 1414048095
    [5] => Closed
    [type] => Closed
    [6] => 3
    [priority] => 3
    [7] => 0
    [assignment] => 0
    [8] => 18
)
```

As you can see timestamp is the date. I need to sort it, here is what ive tried:

```
function date_compare($a, $b)
    {
        $t1 = strtotime($a['timestamp']);
        $t2 = strtotime($b['timestamp']);
        return $t1 - $t2;
    }    
    usort($row, 'date_compare');
```

But i get error because of timestamp... Here is error `Warning: Illegal string offset 'timestamp' in /home/...../domains/foxiad.com/public_html/...../modules/ticketsmith/index.php on line 365`

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: delete the strtotime() around the timestamp

Comment: Deleted, same error here it is `Warning: Illegal string offset 'timestamp' in /home/...../domains/foxiad.com/public_html/...../modules/ticketsmith/index.php on line 365`

Comment: *usort($row, 'date_compare');* what is that?

Comment: $row is that array which i showed and date_compare is function

Comment: @donald123 thats a userdefined sort.

Comment: Are you sure $row is not one subarray and you really want to use $row**s** for usort() ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: all basic ways to sort arrays and data in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/reference-all-basic-ways-to-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of array you are showing here looks generated by this kind of thing, which are all seperate arrays.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($variable))
{
    print_r($row);
}
```

You need to build one seprate array, then perform a sort on it.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($variable))
{
    $results[] = $row;
}
```

Then, you will be able to sort that, feeding `$results` to `usort()`